# have any mistake with my last-child selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

```
$(function(){
   $("#mainContainer #container:last-child").css("background-image","url('/images/content-title.png') no-repeat")
})
```

**code above didn't work , nothing happend**

```
$(function(){
   $("#mainContainer #container:last-child").css("background-image","url('/images/content-title.png')")
})
```

**code above work , but it change all the #container background and repeat-y.**

not only the last-child

what i want is change the last-child of #container background image and no-repeat

my html

```
<div id="mainContainer">//width 930px margin 0 auto
  <div id="container">//height 500px test background repeat-y
    dynamic content here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your dynamic content generated by jQuery or your server language like PHP or ASP.NET? If it's generated on the server side could we see what it may look like?

Comment: never mind,i give up already lol...is generated by php , i simply add 1 more div on the footer. thank you for answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this:

```
$("#mainContainer #container > :last-child")
    .css("background","url('/images/content-title.png') no-repeat");
```

1. `#container:last-child` means you're looking for `#container` which is the last child of whatever that element sits inside, **not** the last child *of* `#container`.

   `#container > :last-child`, on the other hand, refers to any element which is the last child of the `#container` element.
2. In order to set *both* a background image *and* a repeat value in the same line, you need to use the shorthand `background` CSS property. Conversely, if you don't want to use a shorthand you can do this instead:

   ```
   $("#mainContainer #container > :last-child")
       .css({
            "background-image": "url('/images/content-title.png')", 
            "background-repeat": "no-repeat"
       });
   ```